# Flutter Update issues

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

My flutter code works perfectly fine and I have run multiple tests on it.
I just decided to install the new VS code updates and restart my VS code application.
All of the sudden I started having the error below and I have searched the entire code for the method but none was found

```
 Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
 lib\main.dart
../../../flutter_windows_1.22.3-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/navigator.dart:3783:32: Error: Getter not found: 'deoNotPop'.
      case RoutePopDisposition.deoNotPop:
                               ^^^^^^^^^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\temp\flutter_windows_1.22.3-stable\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 904

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Users\temp\flutter_windows_1.22.3-stable\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 26s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Someone, please help me

Comment: have you run `flutter pub get`??

Comment: 1) You need to fire flutter clean 
2) flutter create .
3) Flutter pub get

Comment: Yes, i have clean, run flutter pub get but still having the same issue

Comment: The most annoying thing is that i have searched the entire code and the method RoutePopDisposition.deoNotPop is no where to be found even in the build file. Don't know where the error is coming from and it just started this morning.

Comment: My code works now, had to go into the flutter sdk folder and commented the line of code in the file and it worked. Not the best practice but i don't know what to do again. and i might not use the methos anyways.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have inadvertedly modified a Flutter SDK file:

flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/navigator.dart

```
case RoutePopDisposition.deoNotPop:
```

This should say `doNotPop` and not `doeNotPop`. Removing the `e` and saving the file should fix it. You can run `git status` in your Flutter SDK to see if there are other changes that may need reverting.